# Groovy: How to join map values/why inconsistent results?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, linkedhashmap

Why does the following Groovy script:

```
def d = ["foo":"lorem", "bar":"ipsum", "baz":"dolor"]
def j = d.inject([]) { result, e -> result += e.value }.join()
```

...result in the desired value of `j`: `loremipsumdolor` at https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ but result in the following error when run from my Jenkinsfile:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method join() on null object
```

My Jenkins server is running Groovy 2.4.12.
I don't know, and am unclear how to determine, what version of Groovy is running at https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/.

The above code is inspired from https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-inject-method.html

**Why does the above script cause an error when run from Jenkins, and what is another elegant/Groovy-idiomatic way to achieve the desired functionality: joining all map values?**

Comment: `d.values().join()` ?

Comment: @tim_yates - LOL! I didn't realize it could be that simple! If you decide to write up an answer, I hope it shows up in future search results, because I did not find something so simple and elegant when I googled "groovy join map values"

Comment: @tim_yates - I found a different solution, which involves explicitly `return`ing `result` in each iteration of the closure - but your solution is more elegant by far. I'm still academically curious why the same code behaves differently in different Groovy runtime environments. I'm guessing it has to do with the Groovy language/interpreter version -- but that's getting far outside my area of competence.

Comment: I'm not sure what, but from a lot of the questions here Jenkins does some odd things to some areas of Groovy, and things that work in the groovy console, don't work in Jenkins...  Hopefully a Jenkins expert will be able to explain why.